# Gmail - Moving between category tabs

Tags: gmail, gmail-api, gmail-imap

Can a third-party email-client make Gmail learn to categorize all future emails from a sender to be labeled in a particular category?

In short, do we have any way to do what Gmail does when I drag and drop an email to a particular category tab? See screenshot below.

[image: This is what Gmail does when you drag a message to a category tab]

I know we can create filters using Gmail API, but that's different from what Gmail does. For example, the above screenshot does not create any visible filter in Gmail.

Comment: It maybe that Google has integrated Artificial Intelligence in their products which is rampant in Silicon Valley nowadays.

Comment: @noogui ya, my question is more around: if I use Gmail and a third party email client to access it, can I get the above functionality?

Comment: you never know until you try

Comment: The Inbox 'categories' seem to be completely absent from their IMAP specification.